# Associating to wifi just using a shell command without writing a config file

Tags: networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

The system is Debian 10. I would like to seal the wifi passphrase using a TPM and execute a shell command to associate the wifi card to an access point. The seal & unseal is complete. I have unsealed the passphrase and have it ready either as environment variable or stored in the kernel keyring.

Then I execute `nmcli dev wifi connect $essid password $password`. Does the password get stored anywhere on the filesystem?

Is there maybe an easier way to associate to a wifi in an ad-hoc way just using a shell command?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect without creating a configuration file:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i <interface_here> -c <(wpa_passphrase  "SSID" passphrase)
dhclient
```